# Proguard keep by source file path

Tags: proguard, android-proguard

Proguard has options for `-keep`-ing a class based on its package name/hierarchy.

Is it possible to `-keep` based on the source file's actual path?

Example:

`java/com/a/b/c/Class.java` contains `package com.a.b.c.Class`
`tests/com/a/b/c/ClassTest.java` contains `package com.a.b.c.ClassTest`

There may be a large number of "*Test" classes and I want to Proguard `-keep` everything under `tests/*` for testing purposes.  It should not keep any classes which happen to match "*Test" outside of the `tests/*` directory.

It doesn't seem like this would be possible with package matching since it has the same package as those classes under `java/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. ProGuard does not consider the file path when applying rules.

You could use annotations for your test classes, e.g.

```
@TestClass
public class MyTest {
   ...
}
```

and then add a configuration like this:

```
-keep @TestClass class * { *; }
```